# BLE Server C# Notify Characteristic

Tags: c#, windows, server, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to make BLE server using C# on Windows 10 but I couldn't find any source for notify characteristic. Is there any examples I can use ? If so please show me... Thank you..

```
public async Task<bool> AddReadNotifyCharacteristicAsync(Guid characteristicId, string characteristicValue, string userDescription = "N/A")
        {
            var charactericticParameters = new GattLocalCharacteristicParameters
            {
                
                CharacteristicProperties = GattCharacteristicProperties.Read,
                StaticValue = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(characteristicValue).AsBuffer(),
                ReadProtectionLevel = GattProtectionLevel.Plain,
                UserDescription = userDescription
            };
            var characteristicResult = await _gattServiceProvider.Service.CreateCharacteristicAsync(characteristicId, charactericticParameters);
            var readCharacteristic = characteristicResult.Characteristic;
            
            readCharacteristic.ReadRequested += async (a, b) =>
            {
                await _logger.LogMessageAsync("read requested..");
            }; 

            var writer = new DataWriter();

            await readCharacteristic.NotifyValueAsync(writer.DetachBuffer());

            readCharacteristic.SubscribedClientsChanged += async (a, b) =>
            {
                await _logger.LogMessageAsync("notify requested..");
            };

            void _notifyCharacteristic_SubscribedClientsChanged(GattLocalCharacteristic sender, object args)
            {
                new GattSubscribedClient clients = sender.SubscribedClients;
            }

            return characteristicResult.Error == BluetoothError.Success;
        }
```

Comment: Simple add characteristic with Notifiable (or indicatable) flag. Then call NotifyValueAsync() https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.gattlocalcharacteristic.notifyvalueasync?view=winrt-22000

Comment: Hello, first of all, thank you for your answer! I tried it like the code I posted above, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: CharacteristicProperties = GattCharacteristicProperties.Read | GattCharacteristicProperties.Notify

Comment: Thank you but I get an error in "new GattSubscribedClient clients = sender.SubscribedClients;" this part.

Comment: SubscribedClients is the list, not the single GattSubscribedClient object: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.gattlocalcharacteristic.subscribedclients?view=winrt-22000#Windows_Devices_Bluetooth_GenericAttributeProfile_GattLocalCharacteristic_SubscribedClients